# Groovy regular expression - is it different to "normal" regular expressions?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am having issues generating a regular expression that works in Groovy.

My aim is: given a string like:

/products/prodA/index-tab2.html

to get a match that returns a match if the string after the last / contains "-tab"n".html"

My initial attempt is with

```
([^\/]+)(?<=-tab[0-9]\.html$)
```

which I tested here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ against the following test data:

```
/products/prodA/index-tab2.html
/products/prodA/index.html 
/products-tab2/prodA/index-tab2.html
```

and got matches on "index-tab2.html" - so far so good (or so I thought).

Next step is to put this into Groovy:

```
log.info("KPF: pageName is ${pageName} ")

def matcher = pageName =~ /([^\/]+)(?<=tab[0-9]\.html$)/
if (matcher.matches()) {
  log.debugEnabled && log.debug("KPF: Filename has tab = $filename")
} else {
  log.debugEnabled && log.debug("KPF: Filename does not have tab")
}
```

however when I test the code with the input

/products/prodA/index-tab2.html
(there is no trailing space - verified - but left out of this example)

I get the following logged:

```
2013-07-02~12:51:10 INFO  (xxx.site.controllers.PageController @ line 35) KPF: pageName is /products/prodA/index-tab2.html  (xxx)
2013-07-02~12:51:10 DEBUG (xxx.site.controllers.PageController @ line 44) KPF: Filename does not have tab (xxx)
```

So which regex is "wrong" and how do I get the match I need?

Comment: There are lots of favors of regular expressions, so I'm curious which flavor you consider "normal"?

Comment: Codie - thats why I put "wrong" in quotes ;-) As I am currently working with Groovy if someone knows a site similar to the gskinner one that has the same flavour of regular expression handling as Groovy is using then I would happily use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matcher.matches()` requires that the *whole* string match the regular expression, so it will only return `true` if `pageName` contains no slashes at all.  You probably want to use `find()` instead of `matches()`, which returns true if a match is found anywhere in the string.

```
log.info("KPF: pageName is ${pageName} ")

def matcher = pageName =~ /([^\/]+)(?<=tab[0-9]\.html$)/
if (matcher.find()) {
  log.debugEnabled && log.debug("KPF: Filename has tab = ${matcher.group(1)}")
} else {
  log.debugEnabled && log.debug("KPF: Filename does not have tab")
}
```

Or indeed just `if(matcher)` as a `Matcher` coerces to boolean in Groovy by calling `find()`.  This is done to support syntax like

```
if(pageName =~ /..../)
```

but in your case you need a reference to the actual `Matcher` in order to extract the parenthesised group.

Comment: Doh! Hangs Head In Shame because I *knew* that, but forgot - great community support - thanks Ian.

Comment: You can get away with: `if( matcher ) log.debug("KPF: Filename has tab = ${matcher[0][1]}")`